# Proper time and asymptotic flatness

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, general-relativity, geodesics

I have asked this question at [physics stackexchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225575/proper-time-and-asymptotic-flatness) but got no response. I thought I could try my luck here:

I'm trying to understand the concept of [asymptotic flatness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotically_flat_spacetime) in general relativity, and came up with the following question:

If the proper time $\tau$ is infinite for a timelike geodesic, does it mean that the spacetime is asymptotically flat? Or am I confusing concepts here?

Would be grateful for any clarifications.

Comment: Counterexample: de Sitter space has timelike geodesics of infinite proper time length, yet is not asymptotically flat.

Comment: I see. So then, in general, is there a way to formulate the concept of asymptotic flatness using geodesics? @IgorKhavkine

Comment: Not as far as I know. Asymptotic flatness has to do with the existence of an asymptotic region approaching Minkowski space. There might be multiple ways of characterizing, but I don't know of a simple way of doing that using only geodesics.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine could it be useful to calculate the proper time of timeline geodesics? (referring to characterization of asymptotic flatness) For a flat space, time like geodesic would maximize proper time… Is my direction correct?

Comment: @GregVoit: timelike geodesics are defined as maximizers of proper time (at least locally). Flatness have nothing to do with it. From the equivalence principle there's really no way to probe asymptotic structure "locally". At the very least you will need more than just one geodesic (you will need a [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(general_relativity))).